# Google map API error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, geolocation

I am using Artem Google map control in my webpage. I create markers on the map after doing a geolocation mapping for a list of IP addresses.

```
     <div id="mymap">
    <cc3:GoogleMap ID="GoogleMap1" runat="server" Width="1400px" Height="700px"  Latitude="42.1229" Longitude="24.7879"
Zoom="3" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#999999" BorderWidth="1" EnableScrollWheelZoom="true" EnableContinuousZoom="True" ShowScaleControl="True">
    </cc3:GoogleMap>
        </div>
```

This page keeps refreshing after every 1 minute. It all works fine for sometime, but after a while, an error starts showing up in all the browsers.

**IE**: Message: 'sa' is null or not an object
Line: 439
Char: 108
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/362b/maps2.api/main.js

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/362b/maps2.api/%7Bmod_api_gc,mod_drag,mod_ctrapi,mod_zoom,mod_scrwh,mod_apiiw%7D.js

**Firefox**: Error: a is null
Source File: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/362b/maps2.api/main.js
Line: 207

**Chrome**: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sa' of null

The map is still displayed with all its markers. But I can't zoom or drag the map as it becomes static. Also, the infowindow on the markers don't open.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have reached your [geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits) limits.